# lock screen with user and password in java

Tags: java, windows, locking, fullscreen

Good morning,
I need to develop a desktop application in Java that works in this way:

- It's the first software that starts at windows start-up
- The users can't do anything (e.g. to open the task manager, to press the windows key, to minimize, to close or similar) until they type username and password to login and to access to the system
- This application must be connected to online database containing all the username and passwords.

When the users have inserted correct datas, a timer starts and the application works in background, while using the system.

Once the users decide to close the session, they have to logout from this application, then the timer will stop and the software will be again in full-screen

Below I'll explain how the common-use has to be:
1) I start the PC
2) The PC shows to me the application with USERNAME and PASSWORD
3) I type USERNAME and PASSWORD
4) A timer starts
5) I use the PC for X hours
6) I stop to use the PC, then I logout from the application
7) The timer stops, then return to 2)

Is there any API that I can use?

Thank you
Regards

Answer (score 1):

There is no API. In-fact you are trying to design a software which would run at end customer machine but would be the only one accessible. Ideally Java is not used for such purposes. Still if you want to accomplish through Java only break your problem to small tasks and start working one by one:
1) First you need to write java desktop application working as normal java applications (being run by developer every time)
2) Then include your database connectivity
3) include your clocks and functionality to behave the way you need
4) Finally you can use the java run time environment to ensure that it takes the control of the system
5) Lastly your program would need to be fit in start up menu of Windows to ensure it starts just the say it starts antivirus on boot up. and there you go ....